# Unity didn't export the xcworkspace file

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 2019.3.2, and the GoogleMobileAds Plugin (Last version) in my project. But when exporting to Xcode, there's no Xcworkspace file generated!

I've also checked the IOS Resolver settings and choosing the Xcworkspace (check the screenshot below), but it still export only the Xcodeproj file! can you please help?

[image]